# client side pagination on ag grid?

Tags: angular, ag-grid

I have api where i want to get on every call 50 records. But i want to display only 10 by 10 in grid. Any suggestion how can i do that? so when i come to last page that call service again and get next 50. Any suggestion?

```
<ag-grid-angular [rowSelection]="rowSelection" #agGrid style="display: block;width: 100%; height: 300px;" class="ag-fresh" [gridOptions]="gridoptions"
    [rowData]="data.rowData" [pagination]="true" [suppressPaginationPanel]="true" (rowClicked)='onRowClicked($event)' (selectionChanged)='onSelectionChanged($event)' (gridReady)="onGridReady($event)">
</ag-grid-angular>

public gridoptions: GridOptions = {
        'enableSorting': true,
        'enableFilter': true,
        'suppressRowClickSelection': false,
        'groupSelectsChildren': true,
        'debug': false,
        'rowSelection': 'multiple',
        'rowDeselection': true,
        'enableColResize': true,
        'rowGroupPanelShow': 'always',
        'pivotPanelShow': 'always',
        'enableRangeSelection': true,
        'animateRows': true,
        'paginationAutoPageSize': false,
        'paginationPageSize' : 11,
        'columnDefs': [],
        'pagination': false,
        'defaultColDef': {
            'editable': true,
            'enableRowGroup': true,
            'enablePivot': true,
            'enableValue': true
        },
```

Comment: im not sure what code can i use for my example

Comment: By the way, you have both `'pagination': false,` and `[pagination]="true"` in your code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, nevermind my comment. I will give you a full answer. So what you want to do, is to hold and update `rowData` manually somewhere in your app. On Initialization of your component you have to fetch the fist block of data. So you can simply put the call to the httpClient (or the action triggering it if you are using Redux) in `ngOnInit() {...}`.

Then you have to react to the user navigating through the pages and update the `rowData` when he gets to the last page (again, by calling httpClient).

so in your gridOptions define:

```
paginationChanged(event: PaginationChangedEvent) => {
    if (event.newPage) {
        const currentPage: number = gridOptions.api.paginationGetCurrentPage();
        if (this.data.rowData.length <= (currentPage * 10)) {
            // fetch again
        }
    }
}
```

make sure you update the whole `data` object instead of just pushing new items to the `rowData`-array in order to trigger change detection:

```
rowData = [...oldRowData, ...newChunk];
```

Comment: Hi @Phil i have added the onpaginationChanged event, but the event is not getting triggered, any idea ?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72640422/onpaginationchanged-event-is-not-working-in-ag-grid

Answer (score 0):

i hope in my case in angular can help you, you can add `[pagination]="true` and `[paginationPageSize]=10` in .html

```
<ag-grid-angular 
     [rowSelection]="rowSelection" 
     #agGrid 
     style="display: block;width: 100%; height: 300px;" class="ag-fresh" 
     [gridOptions]="gridoptions"
     [rowData]="data.rowData" 
     [pagination]="true" 
     [suppressPaginationPanel]="true" 
     (rowClicked)='onRowClicked($event)' 
     (selectionChanged)='onSelectionChanged($event)' 
     (gridReady)="onGridReady($event)">

     [pagination]="true"
     [paginationPageSize]=10

</ag-grid-angular>
```