# onPaginationChanged event is not working in ag-grid

Tags: pagination, ag-grid

I am using ag-grid onPaginationChanged event to do api call for server side pagination so that I need to pass the page number to the api.

But the event is not getting triggered.

```
this.gridOptions = {
     
      
      onPaginationChanged: this.paginationChanged
}

paginationChanged =(event: PaginationChangedEvent) => {
    console.log("sdsds");
    if (event.newPage) {
      console.log("event.newPage", event.newPage);
    //  const currentPage: number = this.gridOptions.api.paginationGetCurrentPage();
     // if (this.data.rowData.length <= (currentPage * 10)) {
          // fetch again
     // }
  }
}
```

Comment: a stackblitz or similar that demos the issue would really help us to diagnose the problem